# how to cast/convert a Collection<T> to an Collection<U>

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, collections, type-conversion

is there an easy way to do this **whiteout using a loops**?

how my classes looks like

```
class T
{
    //some stuff
}

class U
{
     //some stuff

    public U(T myT)
    {
         //some stuff
    }
}
```

i found on my research the following method [List.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf) but it is only for List now i want to know if someone knows a way to achieve this for Collections.

i would prefer a generic solution but anything that solve this in a performant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LINQ select for this:

```
var enumerableOfU = collectionOfT.Select(t => new U(t));
```

If you want to enumerate `enumerableOfU` multiple times, you should append `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` after the `Select`.

Please note that this *internally* still uses loops, but you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: i thought LINQ isn't that performant? sure at the moment it doesn't matter for me but my list will grow

Comment: @WiiMaxx LINQ queries are slower than for-loops not slow in general, obviously since the way LINQ works results in the construction of additional intermediate objects it will be more expensive but it's not expensive in general. Ask yourself if you need that performance first and if you do, just do it in a for-loop and be done with it.

Comment: @WiiMaxx: LINQ adds a small, *constant* overhead. In other words, the overhead will not grow if the number of items in your collection increases.

Comment: @WiiMaxx LINQ is lazy, in the sense that there is very little cost if you don't end up using the complete result. That might be a very interesting property in itself that can lead to massive performance gains in some situations, despite LINQ being more expensive in the general case than a for-loop.

Comment: ah you mean if it takes 5 sec more versus the for-loop it doesn't grow with my items right, it is just 5sec slower?

Comment: @JohnLeidegren i use the complete result T(Model) is my Colltetion of objects i get from my DAL now i would cast it to a collection of U(ViewModel) for my UI

Comment: @WiiMaxx: Yes, but its most likely more like 5 Milliseconds - if it is even that much.